# why element.Text= not work

Tags: c#, string, winforms, text, label

Try to do next - i want to check if some information is already exist if csv file, if yes - open form with label, and put to this label information from file
Code is next:

```
public void getEventTime(string filePath, string currDate, string currentDateTimeHM)
    {
        //reading the *.csv file and convert to the array of data
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);

        //create array for getting any vlaue from string
        string[] arrOfData = sr.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        sr.Close();

        List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        bool status=false;//variable for showing form if event exist

        foreach (var l in arrOfData)
        {
            if (l.Contains(currDate) && l.Contains(currentDateTimeHM))
            {
                string[] temp = l.Split(',').Take(5).ToArray();
                notLabel.Text = temp[1].ToString();
                status = true;
            }
        }
        if (status)
        {
            //show Notification Form
            Form NotificationForm = new Notification();
            NotificationForm.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

all works perfect - if information exist - new form opens, but `notLabel.Text = temp[0].ToString();` this part have return nothing. During debuging i got next 
[image]

means that code is correct but in strange for me reason result in programm - without this text.
where I make some mistake?

Below form with label
[image]

checked

[image]

few rows from file NotificationDesigner.Form.cs

```
        this.notLabel.AutoSize = true;
        this.notLabel.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(204)));
        this.notLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 22);
        this.notLabel.Name = "notLabel";
        this.notLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(34, 13);
        this.notLabel.TabIndex = 0;
        this.notLabel.Text = "label";
```

Comment: Are you adding the Label in the designer or programmatically?

Comment: i add manually label to the disigner form, name - notLabel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where do you call the method `getEventTime` and what is `notLabel`.

if the method `getEventTime` is called and set the `notLabel.Text` but after that the text is set again to `string.Empty` that there is the problem, so you should probably search or debug every change to `notLabel.Text`.

are you sure the it is `notLabel` the it is shown in the form? you can check that by registering to the `mouseDown` event and see that it is called when you click on the Label

one more thing, add `break;`
after your line

```
status = true;
```

go to the design and press the label, press F4 and search the `name` property, i bet it is not `notLabel`:

[image]

**EDIT**

i think i fount your problem

correct me if i'm wrong but this lines

```
    if (status)
    {
        //show Notification Form
        Form NotificationForm = new Notification();
        NotificationForm.Visible = true;
    }
```

are happening after you change the text... when what you meant is:

```
public void getEventTime(string filePath, string currDate, string currentDateTimeHM)
{
    Form NotificationForm = new Notification();
    //reading the *.csv file and convert to the array of data
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);

    //create array for getting any vlaue from string
    string[] arrOfData = sr.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    sr.Close();

    List<string> lines = new List<string>();
    bool status=false;//variable for showing form if event exist

    foreach (var l in arrOfData)
    {
        if (l.Contains(currDate) && l.Contains(currentDateTimeHM))
        {
            string[] temp = l.Split(',').Take(5).ToArray();
            NotificationForm.NotText = temp[1].ToString();
            status = true;
        }
    }
    if (status)
    {
        //show Notification Form

        NotificationForm.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

and in the notification form do

```
  public string NotText
  {
     set { notLabel.Text = value; }
  }
```

Comment: `get event` i call in main form on-load `eventViewer.getEventTime(FilePath, currentDateTimeD, currentDateTimeHM);` notLabel - it's notification label means

Comment: how can i search every changing of notLabel.text? only using debug? ther is no any additional place in code where i use it. Maybe problem is because i make some changes of lebal in one part of code but call the windows in another? and during calling window this labels become Empty?

Comment: @Kirill try this: make a button, that upon pressing the button you call getEventTime, and tell me if that worked

Comment: try with button - qorks - windows shows but labela without changes

Comment: try to add break - result is the same

Comment: what do u mean? the label didn't changed even though the debug said otherwise? @Kirill

Comment: i mean that during debuging when i put mouse to the element - i see that it changes Text to text from file - as i required, but than, when windows is apear, text on label - without any changing. one more thing - i put on label some starting text, like "here will be event name", can it injure to the working of programm. also maybe ther is some propertiest thet must be changed for correct working of code? i check it by myself - nothing like this not found, but maybe I'm forgor something

Comment: try it - nothing to change, but i found that after launching this method first off all started this methos - it running - result ok, then start to running `if (status)` statement and in the end launching NotificationForm.designer, where i can find simething like this `this.notlabel.Text = "";`. but in this file i found remark - that say `please do not change this code`. so think - my code i'ts something like - doing what i want, than program create form and put all labels to default statu (as during creating). If I'm right - what can i do with it? Are ther is some mistake in my code logic?

Comment: see emy edit in post - add part of code from file - according to debug process this file running after initialization of `NotificationForm.visible =true;` so think thats why i have nothing on my labels, but how can i change it?

Comment: @Kirill i need to go, but i'll be back tomorrow. my code should have cause the code in the NotificationForm.designer to run before your code and thus end the problem... i don't know what went wrong, but i think that if you'll carefully debug it you'll be able to change the code so the designer is running before your code

Comment: ok, anyway thanks - try to find reason - if find - put answer here

Comment: @Kirill good morning, maybe would you like to share the entire solution and i'll try to find the problem? you can sand me via facebook or email - liraneli@gmail.com

Comment: Good morning, i found the problem: as i use this method from mainForm, in mainForm i create object of this class (with notification), than call method, and inside this methos i create additional object of same class, so as result every time i send infromation in old form and show new one. Correction - remove object  from method and add `eventViewer.Notification.Show();` to main form . it's my fall - dont show in question how i use this method - if interesting - can send you full code by email. thanks